# how to upgrade a Facebook app on iOS to OAuth 2.0 and HTTPS

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, upgrade, oauth-2.0

I have just received an email from Facebook:

> Reminder: Upgrade Your App to OAuth 2.0 and HTTPS by October 1st

Some of my app use Facebook API on iOS. Please help me because I don't know what I have to do. If I use the last SDK for iOS, what do I have to do more? Do I have to change the app settings in Facebook?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you are using the Facebook iOS SDK you are already good to go.

http://www.insidefacebook.com/2010/08/12/facebook-adds-graph-api-oauth-2-0-integration-to-ios-sdk/